# How to insert a calculated SUM in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-insert

I have a table with those column PRICE int value , QUANTITE int value , TOTAL int value
I want to insert the PRICE and QUANTITE and let the SQL  query calculate the total for me her is how my query look like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (PRICE,QUANTITE,TOTAL)
VALUES ('4800','3',PRICE * QUANTITE);
```

it didn't work , so I tried with another query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (PRICE,QUANTITE,TOTAL)
VALUES('4800','3',SELECT (QUANTITE * PRICE) as TOTAL from table_name);
```

this didn't work also, any suggestion?

Comment: If you dont want to repeat the values on INSERT use a trigger to update the TOTAL Column.Also sql server and mysql are different things.

Comment: Drop the column altogether.  One of the rules of normalization is to not store calculated values.

Comment: Give your table value and error message.

Comment: You could of course add a computed column to your table to calculate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(PRICE, QUANTITE, TOTAL)
    SELECT price, quantite, price * quantite
    FROM (SELECT 4800 as Price, 3 as Quantite) t;
```

Note:  you shouldn't use single quotes for numeric constants.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif . . . As the OP you have the choice of accepting whichever answer you prefer.  I am curious, though, why after all this time you would choose another answer, that seems more complicated, because it requires the declaration of a variable.

Comment: I didnt pay attention I taught it was your answear that i have accepted , and now 4 years later i relise that no i did accept the wrong answear lol @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

do it with variable

```
DECLARE @I INT 
INSERT INTO table_name 
SELECT PRICE,QUANTITE,@i=(QUANTITE * PRICE)  
from table_name
WHERE PRICE=4800 AND QUANTITE=3
```